# The meaning of "fresh off of"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

I came across this sentence in an [article online](https://gizmodo.com/mark-zuckerberg-i-can-barely-handle-this-cnn-interview-1823975305):

> Facebook CEO Mark Zuckerberg, **fresh off of** not apologizing for the social media giant’s failure to prevent sketchy election data firm Cambridge Analytica from partnering with a similarly sketchy app to allegedly scrape 50 million users’ profile data, briefly emerged from his gilded panic room on Wednesday evening for an interview with CNN’s Laurie Segall in which he largely repeated his PR department’s talking points.

I can't really find **fresh off of** defined in online dictionaries, but I did find **fresh out of** defined in [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fresh+out+of), one of its definitions being:

> Having just completed a particular task or goal, often a level of education.

Is this the meaning that the author of the article had in mind? And is **fresh off of** a common and idiomatic phrase, interchangeable with **fresh out of**? What does this sentence mean then?

Comment: to be fresh off of something means: to have just done it, yes. Here, it means "to have just ***not*** done it". I have to say, though, the writing is awful. It is a bad choice of words here. Normally, it would be used in a declarative sense,not a negative one. sketchy here too is not great. I would have used dodgy.

Answer (score -1):

That dictionary definition applies here, yes.
The phrase refers to being 'fresh off the boat' as a new immigrant to a country.